# Synchronize object

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

Having object that has extensive API list.

What is the best way to synchronize this object, i.e. the object already exists in legacy code and used in hundreds of lines of code.

The naive way is to wrap each API call to object with `std::mutex`. Is there an easier or elegant way to do it?

I have tried below code, however would like to get opinion on it or alternative solutions .

Below is template wrapper class that lock the object during the usage , in an automatic way. i.e. locks the object on creation and unlocks upon destruction.

This pattern is very similar to scope lock, however it's useful only for static objects/singletons, it wouldn't work for different instances of a given object

```
template <typename T> class Synced
{
    static std::mutex _lock;
    T& _value;
    public:
    Synced(T& val) : _value(val)
    {
        std::cout << "lock" << endl;
        _lock.lock();
    }

    virtual ~Synced()
    {
        std::cout << "unlock" << endl;
        _lock.unlock();
    }

    T& operator()()
    {
        return _value;
    }
};

template <class T> std::mutex Synced<T>::_lock;
```

example class to be used with Synced template class
 this could be example of a class mentioned above with  tens of API's

```
class Board
{
    public:
    virtual ~Board() { cout << "Test dtor " << endl; }
    void read() { cout << "read" << endl; }
    void write() { cout << "write" << endl; }
    void capture() { cout << "capture" << endl; }

};
```

example of usage , basic calls , the Synced object isn't bounded to scope , thus the destructor is called immediately after semicolon

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    Board b;


    Synced<Board>(t)().read();
    cout <<"  " <<  endl;

    Synced<Board>(t)().write();
    cout << "  " << endl;

    Synced<Board>(t)().capture();
    cout << "  " << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Here below is output of above example run :

```
lock
read
unlock

lock
write
unlock

lock
capture
unlock

Test dtor
```

Comment: Is it an option to extend your legacy object with a recursive `std::mutex` and just take the lock on method entry? Then you do not need any change to the client code.

Answer (score 0):

I only use mutexes for very small critical sections, a few lines of code maybe, and only if I control all possible error conditions.  For a complex API you may end up with the / a mutex in an unexpected state.  I tend to tackle this sort of thing with the [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern).  Whether or not that is practical depends on whether or not you can reasonably use serialization / deserialization for this object.  If you have to write serialization yourself then consider things like API stability and complexity.  I personally prefer [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) for this sort of thing when using it is practical, your mileage may vary.